# Kurento problems with STUN/TURN servers

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, kurento

So the problem I am having is that the WebSocket connection is working on my KurentoMediaServer, but no data is getting transferred (empty remote URLs). I know that this is because my KurentoMediaServer is running behind a NAT (google compute server), but the STUN/TURN server that I am using does not seem to be working.

This is what my WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini looks like:

```
; Only IP address are supported, not domain names for addresses
; You have to find a valid stun server. You can check if it works
; using this tool:
;   http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
stunServerAddress=173.194.66.127
stunServerPort=19302
; turnURL gives the necessary info to configure TURN for WebRTC.
;    'address' must be an IP (not a domain).
;    'transport' is optional (UDP by default).
turnURL=test%40gmail.com:testpassword@66.228.45.110:3478
```

I have tested this opening all my ports temporarily to see if that was the issue, but it was not. Also test%40gmail.com is my numb TURN registered username and testpassword is my password.

I should also mention that I have my KurentoMediaServer and Application (java server) running behind the same NAT, but I have my webpage running on a separate network. Is there something I need to do with Kurento-Utils.js in order for my webpage to run a separate NAT from my app and kurento media server?

Comment: Any updates on this? Was it solved?

Answer (score 3):

The STUN server you've entered is not working, and the TURN server yields a possible authentication error with those credentials, though it returns some `srflx` candidates (remember TURN servers are also STUN servers)

When facing an issue like this, the first thing is to check the STUN and TURN servers using [this](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) very useful test page.

You should

- Look for a valid STUN server
- Disable the TURN configuration in you KMS config file, to single out the failure to one server or the other
- Make sure everything is working using STUN
- Test your TURN server using the test page
- Enable TURN and make sure your TURN server is working with Kurento